# Cannot install AdHoc or Dev IPAs on iOS10 only

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios10, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

We have a problem on iOS10 only.

None of our in-house IPAs, neither DEV-signed nor ADHOC-signed, none can be installed on devices running iOS10.

The same IPAs install fine on iOS9 devices. Same app can be installed on same devices when downloaded from AppStore.

The error message during installation (using Xcode) is "Certificate is expired or invalid". But as I said, it works fine on iOS9, and I've triple checked that the certificate and provisioning profiles used are valid till the rest of the year.

In device console logs, the only thing relevant that I found was:

```
ApplePinningAllowTestCertsiPhoneApplicationSigning not true
```

Comment: have you tried to go to the preferences -> accounts click on view all and download them all again to compile the app?

Comment: Yes, I've re-downloaded the mobile provisioning files. But the error message is not even about that, it's about the certificate.

Comment: So the same mac and the same version of Xcode, you can build to iOS9 devices, but you try to build on the same machine to an iOS 10 device, it fails? And when you look in your Keychain Access app on the Mac, you can see the iOS Development cert showing as valid, along with a private key associated with the cert?

Comment: @wottle builds succeed, resulting in an IPA (I am not making multiple IPAs here). That IPA can be installed on devices running iOS9 but cannot be installed on devices running iOS10, complaining of invalid/expired certificate. Yes, Keychain shows certificate as valid till Fall 2017

Comment: How many iOS 10 devices have you tried?  You can get this error if the device's date/time settings are off.

Comment: @wottle date/time was the first thing I verified. Tested on 3 different iOS10 device. The other dozen or so running iOS9 work.

Comment: Honestly, I would probably try to start with a clean slate. Delete cert and provisioning profile from mac(s), generate new certificate and new provisioning profiles, and do a clean build.